How can I get the vertical line for cursorcolumn in Vim editor?
I have currently set cursorline and cursorcolumn in /etc/vimrc. I am unable to set the cursorcolum to show as vertical line. By default it is block and I was able to change it to underline, but vertical line does not work. This is what it's like:

This is what I would like see.

I have tried different options from different sites, but could not get a solution. Is it possible to do this?

It is impossible.

To expand on my comment, the only styling attributes available are listed under :help highlight-term:
bold
underline
undercurl       not always available
underdouble     not always available
underdotted     not always available
underdashed     not always available
strikethrough   not always available
reverse
inverse         same as reverse
italic
standout
nocombine       override attributes instead of combining them
NONE            no attributes used (used to reset it)

to which you can add :help highlight-ctermbg for a solid rectangle.
As you can see, there is no "sideline"/"rightline"/whatever attribute, so what you ask is impossible.
Note that those limitations are not strictly speaking Vim's, as they are inherited from terminals and terminal emulators.

Thank you. I was also searching for possible options for the cursor.
